# Whats the correct term for a “diamond” an directed acyclic graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What's the correct term for a "undirected cycle" in a directed cycling graph - when there's more than one path between nodes? I'm calling them "diamonds", but is there a better term?

Comment: Do you mean _arbitrary_ undirected cycles, or only undirected cycles composed of two directed paths?

Answer (score 2):

undirected cycle